# Can I use "skywatcher" instead of "astronomer"?

Tags: word-choice

Is this a legitimate word? A skywatcher? As a word meaning a person who observes stars and celestial objects? I want to use something less academic than an astronomer. I googled it but I'm not so sure. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Karia How do you like "skygazer"? http://neilenglish.net/becoming-a-stargazer-first-steps/

Comment: Use "stargazer" rather than "skywatcher".

Comment: Thank you! The dictionary suggested the word "skywatcher" as a synonym of "astronomer", but I guess it is not generally used. Stargazer will do! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. One more thing. The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: The phrase "watchers of the skies" has been used as the title of a [popular history of astronomy book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6899324-watchers-of-the-skies) by Willy Ley. However, I think that present-day astronomers spend very little if any time actually looking at the sky.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an actual word, but it doesn't convey what you want. The sky is high, but stars are far further.

When I hear 'skywatcher', I'm more inclined to think about weather forecasters, plane spotters, bunny-in-cloud-seers, and so on. And Jedis. Look, Skywatcher!

Others have already mentioned **stargazer**, which sounds relatively familiar. Perhaps **spacegazer** if you want to be a bit more broad and include planets, moons, asteroids?

Comment: +vote because this is an *answer* that mentions *stargazer*